# Making CSS triangle on IMG responsive

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, css-shapes

Looking to make responsive triangle on image, but it doesn't resize and it becomes out of alignment at all. How to fix it?

[image]

```
        .image {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .image:after {
            content: '';
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 20px solid transparent;
            border-right: 20px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 20px solid #f5f5f5;
            position: absolute;
            left: 45%;
            top: 63%;
            transform: translatex(-50%);
            /** making it horizontally center **/
        }
```

```
<div class="image">
     <img src="img/frankie.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Comment: That's because there's nothing constraining the `img` to the dimensions of `.img`. Add `img { width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `position:relative` to parent(in your case `.image`) with [bootstrap position](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/)

Second use `bootstrap-4 classes` as [`w-100`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) to `.image/img`

[Code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayv9sohp/)

```css
.image:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #f5f5f5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 63%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="image w-100 position-relative">
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdzwt.jpg" class="img-fluid  w-100">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make this responsive? http://jsfiddle.net/lucasgar/78kobc4q https://prnt.sc/nbhha7